# Redirect Domain to sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I am trying to redirect all traffic that goes to www.century21.bh to century21.bh/map

I have tried to work with the .htaccess with no luck. I had some minor success with cPanels redirect.

It redirected all the homepage traffic, but it didn't redirect for example. www.century21.bh/OldPage.html

Here is what I have:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) /map/$1
```

Comment: Great. 

But now a new issue occurs:

The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

I deleted everything else out of the file. 

I also want it to redirect http:// with and without www.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.century21\.bh$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /map [L,R=301]
```

This rule would need to go (preferably near the top) of the htaccess file in the document root of the `www.century21.bh` domain.